# tailwind class in npm package doesnt apply

Tags: laravel, npm, package, tailwind-css

I want to apply tailwind class to npm package. I successfully make a component, but tailwind class doesnt apply. I try to use in Laravel framework. This is just for test purpose. I installed correctly Vue and Tailwindcss in Laravel. Component works, but tailwind class doesnt.

This is my component in Vue

```
<template>
<h1 class="bg-blue-600 shadow-md px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4">welcome</h1>
<input type="text">
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'InputText',
  props: {
title: Array
}

}
</script>
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './storage/framework/views/*.php',
    './resources/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/**/*.js',
    './resources/**/*.vue',
    "./node_modules/@testiranjephptest/vue-library9/src/InputText.vue",
    "./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel or php, but here are three questions I'd have: 1) Is the CSS file being loaded into the page? 2) If so, are the correct classes being generated? 3) What exactly do you mean by the classes are not applying? What are you seeing in the browser? What does inspect element's styles pane show you?

Comment: Any news about this ?